# is there a way to send a USB data packet without host permission?

Tags: python, c#, c, usb, libusb

i have an NI USB Data Logger. when i plug-in the device, device sends same 10 byte data every 100 ms before opening the software. i captured this data using an USB packet sniffer software.(assume this data is device id). my question is how the device can send data without its software being open? and how can i find out with which endpoint this packets are sending?
thank you

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want to include `python` , `c` and `c#` tags all in one post ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your first question (why a particular device could be sending 10-byte packets before its accompanying application software is launched). There are numerous possibilities that are in line with the USB spec.

To your 2nd question, you may use a tracing software like WireShark or Microsoft Event Analyzer (the latter has recently reached EOL, though) to find out what endpoints do the transfers belong to and even decode the content to produce an easily-readable outputs (for devices belonging to standard classes).